# How do you set the text of a label to an array value?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uilabel

I would like to set a value of my array to a label.

Array declaration:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Cornell Notes
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    NSString *details[8][8];
    NSString *subtitles[8];
}
```

I am not allowed to do:

```
self.label.text = subtitles[0];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: NSString *subtitles[8]; You have declared it as a string and you are saying Array declaration, Use NSArray instead of NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    NSString *details[8][8];
    NSString *subtitles[8];
}
```

Should Be:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *details;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *subtitles;
```

You could declare it similar to the way you had it, but I believe this is the preferred current syntax.  Others may correct me on this.  Most important is that we declare NSMutableArray's as opposed to NSString's.  You are doing C-style declarations, which will be a bit different with these.  I chose NSMutableArray as opposed to NSArray because it looks like you want to be able to add objects at runtime.

And this:

```
self.label.text = subtitles[0];
```

should be:

```
if (!_subtitles) _subtitles = [NSMutableArray new];
[_subtitles insertObject:self.label.text atIndex:0];
```

This line:

```
if (!_subtitles) _subtitles = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Is just to make sure that our `_subtitles` dictionary exists, and if it does, we make sure that it isn't overwritten.  the `[NSMutableArray new]` syntax is something that I personally like because it looks clean; however, many prefer `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]`.  Just so you're aware.

Comment: Error: No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector 'insertObject:atIndex

Comment: Warning:Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString * from NSMutableArray *

Comment: I accidentally wrote `NSString` as subtitles when I first submitted.  I think you must have seen it before I corrected it.  Look again at the top declaration.

Comment: Make sure subtitles is declared like this: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *subtitles;`

Comment: For multiple labels, would I do this: if (!_subtitles) _subtitles = [NSMutableArray new];
    [_subtitles insertObject:self.sub1lab.text atIndex:0];
    if (!_subtitles) _subtitles = [NSMutableArray new];
    [_subtitles insertObject:self.sub2lab.text atIndex:1];

Comment: You can use `addObject:` to add an object to the end of an array.  Inserting at index 0 as we are doing will put the new object at the front of the array and move everything else back one.

Comment: @user3530481 - If you don't select answers when they are correct, and solve your problem, it sets you up for people not to answer.  People are under no obligation to help you.  A simple upvote and/or selecting an answer is an easy way to say thank you.